# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null when trying to alter InnerHtml property of a label (Typescript / HTML / Angular)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, file, innerhtml

I am trying to display the selected files name in a separate label using then InnerHtml property, however nothing is displaying on change (when file is uploaded) and I get an error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null".

My HTML (The input and corresponding label)

```
<button class="image-upload-button" mat-stroked-button (click)="fileUploader.click()" color="primary">Upload Image</button>
<label for="fileUploader" id="file"></label>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" #fileUploader id="fileUploader" (change)="displayFileName($event)" (change)="showPreview($event)"  style="display: none;">
```

My goal is to set the label with the id "file" to show the name of the file uploaded / chosen using the file input. The button is simply a means to open the file explorer.

The on change function "displayFileName($event)" is responsible for setting the value of the label when a new file is uploaded.

DisplayFileName:

```
displayFileName(fileInput: Event) {
    let file = (fileInput.target as HTMLInputElement).files![0];
    let fileName = file.name;
    console.log(fileName);
    const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('#file') as HTMLElement;
    element.innerHTML = fileName;
  }
```

The console logs exactly what I need to display, although I still get the error regardless. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the element rendered at the point you are trying to set the html? Try console logging just before your set html

Comment: It seems as thou it isn't, when using 'console.log(element.innerHtml)', nothing is logged? Despite setting a value for the label element.

Comment: what is element when you console log it?, is it undefined ? or null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for getElementById is wrong, you only pass in the name of the id. That is why element was null.

```
const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('file') as HTMLElement;
```

Also, use it is a good practice to check if element exist or not , so it can be something like

```
 if(element)
   element.innerHTML = fileName;
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzbcu6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)